# Converting user input into hex, joined with NULL?

Tags: python, null, hex

I need to convert user input to Hex, but with NULL characters between each character.

Eg:

User input = 111

Output = b'3100310031

My best attempt looks like this, but it's nowhere near...

```
import binascii
content5 = rb"111"
print(content5)
joiner = "00"
content4 = binascii.hexlify(content5)
print(content4)
content3 = joiner.join(str(content4))
print(content3)
content2 = bytes(content3, 'utf-8')
print(content2)
content = binascii.hexlify(content2)
print(content)
```

But this returns:

```
b'111'
b'313131'
b00'00300100300100300100'
b"b00'00300100300100300100'"
b'62303027303033303031303033303031303033303031303027'
b'3632333033303237333033303333333033303331333033303333333033303331333033303333333033303331333033303237'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't follow how `111` translates to `313131` - what is `111` - a decimal number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hexlify change every byte if the input byte string to its (2 bytes) hexa representation. Just process one byte at a time and join the result:

```
import binascii
content5 = rb"111"
print(content5)
joiner = "00"
content4 = joiner.encode().join(binascii.hexlify(bytes((i,))) for i in content5)
print(content4)
```

It gives as expected:

```
b'111'
b'3100310031'
```